# Messagebox not showing full content

Tags: c#, string, messagebox

I ask a question to the user of my application with a `MessageBox` using the following code:

```
var site = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\Netlogon\\Parameters",
    "DynamicSiteName", "Unconnected") as string;
var selectedSite = (Options.GetUserSetting("Site", "SelectedSite"));

if () // Some checks go here
{
    DialogResult ret = MessageBox.Show(
        string.Format("The selected site is {0}. But you're in {1}...{2}Want to change it ?", selectedSite, site.Trim(), Environment.NewLine),
        "Stupid default selection...",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
        MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    // Some process goes here
}
```

The `MessageBox` is displayed with the following text:

> The selected site is [SelectedSiteNameGoesHere]. But you're in [SiteGoesHere]

which is a bit disturbing because I don't understand why the string is splitted.

If I replace `site` with and hard-coded string, the message is displayed normally.

How can I retrieve the missing part?

### Edit

Here's the output I have:

[image]

And here's the output I want:

[image]

Comment: You've got formatting that uses `Environment.NewLine`.. What did you want to happen? (Apologies for the invalid edit)

Comment: Can't reproduce it here. What is is `site` and `selectedSite`? Here it shows `Want to change it ?` on the second line.

Comment: Are there special characters in your string?

Comment: @PatrickHofman both `site` and `selectedSite` are string, that's why I don't understand why I got this. No special char, the string `site` is `FR-LYON`

Comment: It might help to output the string to a variable first to see what value it has, Its going to be hard to reproduce without knowing exactly what kind of text (i.e length and any special chars) is included

Comment: @Sayse printing the messagebox string in the console, I get the same result. Using `Console.WriteLine("---" + site.trim() + "---")` I get `---FR-LYON` as output

Comment: Again, its hard to see what could be causing the issue unless you have hidden/invalid characters in the string (i.e `\r\n` although this should be fine). Set a breakpoint and check the variables unescaped value

Comment: @Sayse the raw string is `FR-LYON\0S`... You've got the point. But I don't know (yet) how to fix it

Comment: The best place would be wherever you set site in the first place to not have the `NUL` character, you could always try to remove it before doing messagebox but that won't help as much as correctly setting the string

Comment: @Thomas: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5303390/993547) if you need to strip it. As Sayse set: fix the source!

Comment: @Thomas: Is the issue resolved?

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes, I split the site var using split('\0')[0] which is a bit dirty but makes the job